# setFieldsValue with getFieldDecorator custom element structure in getFieldDecorator

Tags: antd

As per the documentation, I know how to use getFieldDecorator and setFieldsValue. But for my scenario, I would like to change a bit in the element structure inside getFieldDecorator like below. In this scenario setFieldsValue not working, any possibilities to get worked. Why I need to use like this for override the display style like a floating label.

```
    <FormItem label={""}>
    {getFieldDecorator('Price', {
        initialValue:'',
        rules: [{ required: true, message: 'amount required!', whitespace: true }]
    })(
        <div className="form-group">
            <Input
                type={"number"}
                placeholder="Enter amount"
                id="amount"
            />
            <label className="custom-label" htmlFor="amount">Amount</label>
        </div>
    )}
</FormItem>
```